# Fabric.js: How to keep text as not rotatable when rotating a group

Tags: fabricjs

How to keep text as not rotatable when rotating a group. In my case `fabric.Rect` and `fabric.Text` are formed as a group. i.e. I want to rotate only rectangle object in a group.

```
      var text = new fabric.Text('text', {
      fontSize: 12,
      top:10,
      left:20,
      });

      var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      width: 50,
      height: 40,
      fill: '#eef',
      });

      var shape = new fabric.Group([rect, text], {
      left: 150,
      top: 100,
      });
```

Answer (score 4):

check my example on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/x5q34etw/55/

it is exactly what you want.

code:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
            selection: true,
            /*theo 12-02-2015*/
            //renderOnAddRemove:false,
            backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        });

var RADIUS_CHILDREN_CIRCLE = 8;
var circles = [];
    function addCirlceTable(left_padding_circle,top_padding_circle,count_chairs,radiusCircle){

                radiusCircle = (typeof radiusCircle === "undefined") ? 35 : radiusCircle;
                var left_p = radiusCircle - RADIUS_CHILDREN_CIRCLE;
                var top_p = radiusCircle  - RADIUS_CHILDREN_CIRCLE; 
                var left_group_circle = left_padding_circle - left_p;
                var top_group_circle = top_padding_circle - top_p; 
                var rad_parent_circle = radiusCircle;
                var radius_children_circle = RADIUS_CHILDREN_CIRCLE;
                var rad_parent_child_circle = radiusCircle+13;

                  var length_line_parent_cirle = (2 * Math.PI *rad_parent_child_circle)*2+radius_children_circle*3;

                  var parent_circle_table = new fabric.Circle({left:left_group_circle,top:top_group_circle,radius:rad_parent_circle, fill:'#FFE2EB',stroke:'#7F7F7F',  hasControls:true,
    hasBorders:true,
    hasRotatingPoint:true,
    selectable:true,
    objectType:'parent'});

circles.push(parent_circle_table);

                  var height_circle = parent_circle_table.getHeight(); 


                  var colors = ['#FFE2EB'];
                  var centerX = left_padding_circle;
                  var centerY = top_padding_circle;
                  var innerRadius = rad_parent_child_circle;
                  var count_child_circle = count_chairs; 

                  var all_circle_lenght  = count_child_circle*(radius_children_circle*2);

                  var length_interval = length_line_parent_cirle/count_child_circle;

                  var interval = length_interval/100;

                  var p =  0;


//canvas.add(parent_circle_table);   

                  for(var i = 0; i < count_child_circle; i++) {

                    var x = centerX + innerRadius * Math.cos(p);
                    var y = centerY + innerRadius * Math.sin(p);


                    var circle = new fabric.Circle({ left: x,top: y, radius: radius_children_circle, fill: colors[0],stroke:'#7F7F7F', hasControls:true,
    hasBorders:true,
    hasRotatingPoint:true,
    selectable:true});
                    circle.set({
                        typeCircle:'chair'
                    });

                    p += interval;

                     // canvas.add(circle);
                      circles.push(circle);

                  } 
                    var objtype = 'grup';
                    var fontSizeTable = 20;
                    var number_table = 1;
                    var N = ""+number_table+"";



        //canvas.add(text);
        //canvas.renderAll();


        var round = new fabric.Group(circles, { left: centerX, top: centerY,originX:'center',originY:'center'});  

                      var tableObject = {
                          "name" : "",
                          "fontSize":"",
                          "diameter": "",
                          "count_chairs": "",
                          "tableNumber": "",
                          "backgroundColor":""
                      };


        //ΒΑΖΩ ΤΑ TEXT ΣΕ ΔΙΚΟ ΤΟΥΣ GROUP
        var texts = [];
        var text = new fabric.Text(N, {fontSize:fontSizeTable ,fontWeight:'bold',originX:'center',originY:'center',top:-5,fill:'black'});

         texts.push(text);                 

        text2 = new fabric.Text('table name rotonta', {fontSize:fontSizeTable ,fontWeight:'bold',originX:'center',originY:'center',top:5,fill:'black'});

         texts.push(text2);

        var textsGroup = new fabric.Group(texts, {
            originX:'center',
            originY:'center',
            objectGroupType:'texts'}
        );  

        round.add(textsGroup);

          canvas.add(round);
          canvas.renderAll();   
            }



addCirlceTable(100,100,12,30)

function onScaling(e){
    console.log('scaling..');     
    console.log()
     e.target._objects[1].set({'stroke':'white'});
     e.target._objects[1].set({'radius':'5'});
//     e.target._objects[1].set({'scaleY':'1','scaleX':'1'});
//     e.target._objects[1].set({'lockScalingX':'true'});

    canvas.renderAll();
}

canvas.observe('mouse:down', function (options)
{
   console.log("mouse down");

    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    });

});

    canvas.on('object:rotating',function(e){
        console.log('object rotate');
        var actObj = e.target;
        actObj._objects.forEach(function(obj){
           if (obj.type == 'group'){
               console.log('angle:'+obj.angle);
               obj.angle = -actObj.angle;
               actObj.setCoords();
               canvas.renderAll();
           }
        });
    });

canvas.observe('object:moving', function (options)
{
    console.log("object move");

    /*canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
        if(obj != options.target){
            obj.top = options.target.top + 30 + 4 + 4;
            obj.left = options.target.left + 30 + 4 + 4

        }
    });*/   
});

canvas.onBeforeScaleRotate = function (e){console.log('before');}
/*canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) { console.log('down'); e.target.set({'fill':'pink'}); canvas.renderAll(); });
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) { console.log('down'); e.target.set({'fill':'red'}); canvas.renderAll(); } );
canvas.on('object:scaling',onScaling);*/
```

Comment: This one behaves strangely after resizing the shape